# Linux Kernel Module / Protocol Registration

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, protocols

My question is regarding Linux Kernel Module Programming, AF Registration, and Protocol Registration (e.g. AF_INET , sock_stream).

Goals:

1. I want to create a new Address Family and register it in the kernel (which is complete in a way)
2. To register a new Protocol to that AF, which will handle the packets incoming, and which I can write an API for.

Problems:

1. I cant find a good example or document to describe how protocol registrations happen.
2. The Kernel Protocols code is, well, different for each protocol, which is not giving me a specific solution.

All I need is a good basic example of AF and Protocol Registration, if possible with comments.

Comment: [Kernel source??](https://www.kernel.org/)